# Sending file over spring rest service via resttemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

Title might look common but none of them fit in my issue.

I have a rest service which accept normal parameters and file in form of multipart.

i want to use resttemplate to send data and file to above rest service.

till the time i was sending normal string data there was no issue. once i add code of sending bytes then i start getting **400 Bad request error.**

if i comment code to send ByteArrayResource then it start working for normal parameters.

below is sample code

Rest service controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/ticket")
public class UserTicketController {

 @RequestMapping(value="/createTicket.do",method={RequestMethod.POST},
        consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE},headers={"content-type="+MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public void createTicket(@ModelAttribute ServiceDeskRequest serviceDeskRequest, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

 }

 }
```

Servicedeskrequest model attribute is

```
 public class ServiceDeskRequest implements Serializable{


private String jsonData;
private MultipartFile attachment;
}
```

application-context.xml

```
 <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
</bean>
```

Client Side code

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> requestParamerterMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();

        requestParamerterMap.add("jsonData", jsonData);
        MultipartFile attachment = userRequest.getAttachment();

        if(attachment!=null && attachment.getOriginalFilename()!=null) {
            ByteArrayResource byteArrayResource = new ByteArrayResource(attachment.getBytes(), attachment.getOriginalFilename());
            requestParamerterMap.add("attachment", byteArrayResource);
        }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(requestParamerterMap, headers);


        String response = restTemplate.postForObject(targetUrl, requestEntity, String.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. There are two piece in this puzzle. No change in service code.

1. Providing right converter to resttemplate. In list of default converts spring doesn't add FormHttpMessageConverter.

   ```
       FormHttpMessageConverter converter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();

       RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
       restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(converter);
   ```
2. overriding bytearrayresource class. plz note you need to override **getFilename** method so that document name can be received at service side.

   ```
        public class MultipartByteArrayResource extends ByteArrayResource{

        private String fileName;

         public MultipartByteArrayResource(byte[] byteArray) {
                super(byteArray);
            }

         public String getFilename() { 
             return fileName; 
           }

         public void setFilename(String fileName) {
             this.fileName= fileName;
          }

      }
   ```

After above changes client code will be

```
       FormHttpMessageConverter converter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(converter);

        MultiValueMap<String, Object> requestParamerterMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();

        requestParamerterMap.add("jsonData", jsonData);

        MultipartFile attachment = userRequest.getAttachment();

        if(attachment!=null && attachment.getOriginalFilename()!=null) {
            //ByteArrayResource byteArrayResource = new ByteArrayResource(attachment.getBytes(), attachment.getOriginalFilename());

            MultipartByteArrayResource resource = new MultipartByteArrayResource(attachment.getBytes());

           //pass file name sepratly 
           resource.setFilename(attachment.getOriginalFilename());

            requestParamerterMap.add("attachment", resource);
        }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(requestParamerterMap, headers);

        String response = restTemplate.postForObject(targetUrls.get("sdCreateTicketsUrl"), requestEntity, String.class);
```

Comment: Did this solution work for you? I did exactly what you said and I am getting 415 Unsupported exception. Only difference I have is requestParamerterMap.add("my_own_name_which_server_accepts", resource)

Comment: Yes, it is working fine for me, if you can share your code then i might help.

Comment: here is the details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527666/415-unsupported-media-type-while-sending-json-file-over-rest-template?noredirect=1#comment90027171_51527666

Answer (score 0):

First, `value="/createTicket.do"` is way off the REST convention. Same goes for `/ticket`.
Creation of a ticket should be done by POST to URL: `.../tickets/`